# Is return will work fine in node.js in normal functions without IO Operations?

Tags: node.js

My function is like this for examle

```
function summ(a,b)
{
 return a+b;
}

module.exports.summ = summ;
```

in other file:

```
var obj = require('./that file')

function app()
{
 var s = obj.summ(7,7);
}
```

if i put `console.log(s);`
it is giving answer perfect.
My doubt is this will come all the time when request is coming frequently since i m using this kind of return in rest api ?
Or call back function is required like that result is

```
function summ(a,b,callback)
{
 callback(a+b);
}
```

and

```
function app()
{
 obj.summ(7,7,function(result){
 var s = result;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your `summ` function behaves in a synchronous manner, like it does in your example code, you don't have to use callbacks.

If you would use asynchronous functions in `summ` (anything I/O related, like reading a file, querying a database, opening a network connection), that *would* require passing a callback function because you would have to wait until the action is completed before you return the result (by calling the callback function).